# eval in chrome package app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, eval, google-chrome-app

I would like to create a package app chrome extension to allow the user to write and execute javascript code (like a javascript console).

I would like to use the `eval()` function to execute the JS code.

The classic javascript `eval` function throws an error when it's called from a chrome extension:

> Uncaught Error: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context

To use `eval` in a chrome extension people need to use a [sandbox](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/sandboxingEval.html), but when I write the sandbox in the manifest I get this error:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>   'sandbox' is not allowed for specified package type (theme, app, etc.).

**UPDATE**

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141501), sandboxes are not supported for package apps, so I have two questions:

1. Is there another method which I can use instead of `eval()`?
2. Is it possible to use `eval` without a sandbox? (I think probably not for security reasons?)

Comment: I don't know much about it, but using [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js/) *might* be a possible (albeit performance-inferior) solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Since at least January 2013, Chrome now permits the [`unsafe-eval`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval) Content Security Policy (CSP) directive, which allows `eval` execution outside of a sandbox:

> The policy against `eval()` and its relatives like `setTimeout(String)`, `setInterval(String)`, and `new Function(String)` can be relaxed by adding **`'unsafe-eval'`** to your policy

Add an appropriate [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) to you extension manifest, like:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

---

The [bug you refer to](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141501) is now marked `fixed`, and has been included since Chrome 22.

Prior to the introduction of `'unsafe-eval'`, there was no way to have the CSP of a `manifest_version: 2` extension allow execution of arbitrary text as code.  [At the time](http://web.archive.org/web/20120812230022/http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html), Google made it clear there was no way to remove this restriction (outside of sandboxing):

> Inline JavaScript, as well as dangerous string-to-JavaScript methods like `eval`, will not be executed... There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes `unsafe-inline` will have no effect. This is intentional.

As mentioned above, this restriction can now be relaxed.

Comment: You could update your answer to mention the `unsafe-eval` directive, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval

Comment: Make sure you reload the extension after you add this in the manifest.json.

Comment: I just want to add that this method only works for extensions, not [packaged apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#what) (since the title of the thread refers to packaged apps).

Comment: @PatriciaGarcia Interesting, yes -- the confusion here seems to be that the term "packaged app" refers to two very different things, and the OP's linked bug report refers to "legacy packaged apps" which basically *are* extensions with an app-screen icon. However, it's likely that the OP didn't realize this about the bug report (neither did I), and actually means modern packaged apps. Thanks for pointing this out; I'll see if I can make the effort to clarify this answer shortly.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you are talking about the new packaged app (manifest version 2), right?

Sandboxes can be used in the new packaged apps, absolutely. Last week I just uploaded [a sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/sandbox) which does exactly that: A window sends a message to a hidden sandboxed iframe, the iframe compiles a handlebar template (here it could use eval instead) and returns the compiled HTML to the hosting page, which shows the result.

You can also check [this other sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/sandboxed-content), which does exactly what you want.

So, to directly answer your questions:

1) No, because of CSP restrictions. The only way to evaluate dynamic JavaScript in Chrome Packaged Apps is the sandboxed iframe. If that's not an option to your app, you could also send and evaluate the JavaScript content in your server and return only the results to the user (although this breaks the offline feature of Chrome Packaged Apps)

2) No, you can only use eval() in a sandboxed iframe.

Comment: Both links are broken

Comment: Fixed. The Github repository has been refactored, which caused the invalid URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try...

```
function evalMe(code){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerText = code;
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
}
```

This should create the same effect, unless they have disabled it as well, but from my knowledge this is fine. Of course if the script `errors` you will not hear about it unless you do some wrapping of the `string` to `eval` e.g.

```
function myHandler(err){
    // handle errors.   
}

function evalMe(code){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var wrapper = '(function(){ try{ @@ }catch(err){ myHandler(err); } })()';
    // Make sure the string has an ending semicolon
    code = code[code.length-1] === ';' ? code : code + ';';

    script.innerText = wrapper.replace('@@', code);
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
}
```

Alternately you could use the official mechanism

http://developer.chrome.com/beta/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript

However this would require you to have a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) and employ [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) between your `app` page and the background page.

**UPDATE:** Working Method

You can create an `eval` like method using an iframe and a `base64` encoded `dataURI` that handles message passing between the extension page and the `<iframe>`. You can grab a working copy of the [code on github](https://github.com/AshHeskes/eval-extension). To use simply clone or download the repo, and install the 'client' `dir` as an unpackaged extension in the chrome extension manager. The code driving the plugin resides in `app.js`

Use the iframeEval to test, the error notification is a little buggy but hey, the `eval` works.

@appsillers In order to get your plugin working without any additional code, you could overwrite the `eval` method on you extensions `window` with the `iframeEval` method in the code.

Comment: `manifest_version: 2` disallows inline scripts, so I expect `evalMe` would produce an error because it injects a `<script>` with an inline script.  Your final suggestion about passing a message to perform an `executeScript` in the background is an interesting possibility, but I think it may be constrained to a separate execution environment, as background pages are.  I'll test to see if that is correct.

Comment: I just tested my first point, and `evalMe` produces the error `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".`

Comment: hmm, let me do some more digging in the docs. As a question, are the evaluated scripts requiring access to the pages `DOM`? or are they `pure.js`

Comment: I'm assuming not, otherwise `eval` would would be pretty dangerous as your giving `eval`'ed code permission to access chrome API's. Unless this is your intention

Answer (score 1):

I came to this answer after an Angular.js chrome app I was starting gave the same error. The author did not mention Angular.js but if anyone else comes across this you need to add an additional directive to your web page e.g.

```
<html ng-app ng-csp>
...
```

This puts angular in CSP-safe mode
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

Answer (score 1):

You could use : $scope.$eval() from angular.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should probably elaborate your question to some extent: have you tested this or do you have some experience, or just threw an idea that came to your mind? Although the latter may be ok, too, more elaborate answers are more welcome. Also, please use code wrappers. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of what will NOT work, as all strings with code will be rejected in Chrome packaged apps:

```
//To run some code from a string without `eval` just do this:
var code = new Function(yourCodeString);
code();
```

Comment: thanks, but same problem: Uncaught Error: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context

Comment: Don't know... Yout might be right, maybe it's a security issue and they disabled it.

Comment: Content Security Policy disallows any kind of dynamic code generation in Chrome extensions - be it `eval()` or `new Function()`.

Comment: Here's a link to the docs on this, which shows examples demonstrating that any string evaluation of JavaScript is not supported. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html.  Consider making an [edit] to your post to correct the inaccuracies, or consider its removal. Good luck! :)

Comment: ok, so I thought your post was a good example of what will *not* work, and the fact that this is here does clear up a few points about exactly how far Google is willing to go to keep us safe ;), so I edited your post to make it correct *and* still useful to future visitors, preserving the core of your answer. Hope this helps! +1