# Eval() in chrome packaged app

Tags: eval, google-chrome-app

I need to use eval in my chrome app. is there any way to do this? It just needs to process a mathematical expression input.

I have tried adding unsafe-eval to the manifest, but it gives me an error a loading the app. Here is the manifest.

```
{
  "name": "Calculator",
  "description": "A calculator for Chrome.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": {"128": "calculator-128.png"}
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eval in chrome package app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897112/eval-in-chrome-package-app).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196121/chrome-app-eval

Answer (score 0):

Read the Chrome documentation ["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval). It answers this common question.

Comment: I know you mean well, but include a short summary. As-is, it's a "link-only answer".